# Show that rank $\mathbb{R} = \omega^{+++++}$

Tags: set-theory

I'm doing some problems from Enderton's Set Theory and this one is chapter 7 exercise 27. Using the definition of $\mathbb{R}$ from Dedkind cuts, we have to show that the rank of the reals is equal to $\omega^{+++++}$ where the rank of a set $A$ is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $A \subseteq V_\alpha$ for the Von Neumann Universe of sets. I don't really understand where to start though. I think maybe I should show that the rank of the integers and rational are $\omega^+$ and $\omega^{++}$ or something, but I'm really stuck overall.

Comment: I think you have a good idea and should continue with it.

Comment: It is often common to denote by $\alpha^+$ the successor cardinal. In either case, using $\omega+5$ is much cleaner.